# Mac, dragging items into desktop folders keeps on opening a finder window immediately

Tags: macos, mac, finder

I'm not sure why I'm suddenly having this problem since I haven't changed any of my finder preferences. Say I drag an image from the browser to a folder on my desktop, it opens up a finder window for that folder immediately. I know if you hover over a folder for a few seconds the finder window for that folder would pop up but now it just does that as soon as I drop something into the folder, no hovering over it. The delay is set to medium with spring loaded folders checked as usual but I don't understand what's changing its behavior. Hope that makes sense, thank you in advance for the assistance.

Comment: I am having the same issue. When dragging images from webpage to desktop it pops up in the finder box. Same settings as above. Checked for Mac updates, nothing....

Comment: Well, I guess I'm glad I'm not the only one. Everything was fine and then I don't know what changed out of nowhere over the past few days.

Answer (score 3):

This issue seems to correspond to the most recent update for Chrome. No fixes yet, but you may want to track the following discussion on the Chrome forum:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/mac/ZO-96WmY6Co

Edit: Seems like there is a fix now: Uploading to Chrome Version 31.0.1650.8 **beta** makes this annoying behavior go away. You can upgrade to the beta version here: https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/beta.html

Answer (score 0):

Same here. Firefox works fine for me, though. Try that maybe?

Comment: ugh, you sound like me doing tech support for Fog Creek: "we don't support Safari, try chrome" But I wanna use Chrome, not Firefox! ;)

Comment: Yeah haha, it seems to be a Chrome issue, but I also prefer using Chrome as well.