# Dragging files onto desktop causes Finder window to unwantedly open

Tags: finder, macos, ui

Every time I drag a file onto my desktop, my finder folder opens. This is new to OS X 10.9 Mavericks. How do I disable this behavior?

Comment: This is really annoying me too, but this does not happen every time.

Answer (score 1):

[I found a similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104152/mac-dragging-items-into-desktop-folders-keeps-on-opening-a-finder-window-immedi) that said it's a [problem with Google Chrome.](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/mac/ZO-96WmY6Co)

Using the latest version of Chrome seems to solve the problem.